# Setting a variable depending on ServerName in CakePHP

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, dns, subdomain

I'm building a little app where people can build some sort of portfolio.

At the moment every user can link to their portfolio using the url `www.example.com/USERNAME` and to handle everything in CakePHP this is the Router rule I'm using:

```
Router::connect('/:user/:action/*', array('controller'=>'pages'), array('named' => array('user')));
```

so links are formed this way: `www.example.com/USERNAME/home` or `www.example.com/USERNAME/contact`

Here comes my question. I'd like for a user to be possible to point his domain's DNS to my IP and change the URLs in `www.mypersonalsite.com/home` and `www.mypersonalsite.com/contact` and so on.

Just like tumblr does...

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: You can't point a record to a domain with a path (like `www.example.com/username`). You can only point it to a domain, like `www.example.com` or `username.example.com`. I suggest rethinking your routing and using a subdomain instead. That's a whole other question, but it's been answered here before I'm sure. There's also a short example here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-0.html#router

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to the user table "personal_domain"

Make sure that your Apache is setup so sites-available for your app will forward all domains that hit the server onto your Cake app

In app_controller add something like this to beforeFilter()

```
$domain = $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ];
$sessionDomain = '';
if( $this->Session->check( 'User.personal_domain' ) )
{
    $sessionDomain = $this->Session->read( 'User.personal_domain' );
}

if( $domain != $sessionDomain )
{
    $User = ClassRegistry::init( 'User' );
    $domainUser = $User->find( 'first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.personal_domain' => $domain
        )
    ) );

    if( empty( $domainUser ) )
    {
        // whatever you usually do for users that don't have their own domain
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->write( 'User.personal_domain', $domainUser [ 'User' ][ 'personal_domain' ] );
        // whatever you usually do, and now you know which user is connecting
    // you should use this info with whatever auth method you use to make sure
    // only that user can login to that domain
    }
}
```